# Use a non-ID field as the ApiResource identifier on a Doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

I am using API Platform 3.2 with Symfony 7.0.

I have a Doctrine entity `SimplePoll` which extends an abstract parent class `Poll`.

`SimplePoll` is an ApiResource. Its ID is an auto-generated `$id` field, which is used internally for FK relations and the like. It also has a `$uuid` field, set on persist, which I'd like to use in all public-facing endpoints instead of `$id`. For example `GET /api/simple-polls/{id}` should use $uuid instead of the $id. The UUID is a `Symfony\Component\Uid\UuidV7` from the `symfony/uid` package, which integrates with Doctrine.

I thought I could accomplish this by setting `ApiProperty(identifier: false)` on `$id` and `ApiProperty(identifier: true)` on `$uuid`, like so:

**App\Entity\Poll**:

```php
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table('poll')]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('SINGLE_TABLE')]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
abstract class Poll
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: false)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: UuidType::NAME, unique: true)]
    #[Groups(['poll:read'])]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    private Uuid $uuid;

    #[ORM\PrePersist]
    public function createUuid(): void
    {
        $this->uuid = Uuid::v7();
    }
}
```

**App\Entity\SimplePoll**:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SimplePollRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['poll:read'],
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['poll:write']
    ]
)]
class SimplePoll extends Poll
{
}
```

However, calling API endpoints that take a poll ID (such as `GET /api/simple-polls/{id}`) returns a 404 when I pass the poll's UUID -- it still only works with the poll's ID.  Additionally, the response of successful `POST` and `PATCH` requests is null (using id), which I suspect is related.

How can I replace `id` with `uuid` in the API without changing the entity's primary key?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change id to uuid on route definition https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters

Comment: I tried this solution, setting the routes via `uriTemplate` in each `ApiResource` operation to use `{uuid}`, but it did not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What the command php bin/console debug:router shows to you? Some times we override our own routes by defining them multiple times. Try editing you routes and use the above command to make sure they are aplied